# Trying to view all logged in Users in Express.js Node.js Passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

Trying to see all sessions of all logged in users in Express Passport, and want be able to see who is currently logged in. Whats the best and quickest means?

I was thinking maybe I could do this at login and update the user model db 'online' boolean variable to true. Then I can run a check on the Users.find() for online=true...

But how will I check this during the event of user logging off or their session ending?

Unless there is an easier way to do this without writing to the db?

I'd eventually like the user to maintain the option to opt out of being viewable online.

Comment: An easy way is to use [node-analytics](https://segment.com/docs/sources/server/node/) module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of using **express-session** (if store is default value: **MemoryStore**) you can get store object and sessions array from **req** object:

```
var sessions = req.sessionStore.sessions
```

For example (for me) it looks like that:

```
{
    KT29eOp9XkzFfXWdz_UVUQMI4Qf3VTxE: 
        '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},
        "passport":{"user":"5a95b34b52670e19200ec48e"}}',
    WW7BAhNNBbuFUsKQ0dbalgToEEfGES8p: 
        '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},
        "passport":{"user":"5a9d56a18149111cf0556991"}}' 
}
```

**user** values in **passport** props are _id of your users in MongoDB User collection.

Comment: for me the user attribute is the users email (username), hows that? and how can i change it to be the id?

Comment: by the way it is not online users but logged in users. means if you log in and leave the page your session will still be in the sessionstore