# Killing a User Session in Passport

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session, passport.js

I want to kick users from their active passport.js sessions.

I'm able to get a users name via this linked method:

[Trying to view all logged in Users in Express.js Node.js Passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104698/trying-to-view-all-logged-in-users-in-express-js-node-js-passport-js/49128290#49128290)

Is there an easy way to kill a current session of a particular user, so they don't have an active 'verified user' session when they log in?

I want to achieve being able to 'kick' someone off the server, basically stripping them of any sessions in any open browsers they might have.

Comment: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/logout/ ?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to throw this check in your deserialization when you determine who the user is based on the token. You could find the user object like normal then check if it has a field saying to not validate the session and not return the user.

For example, if you have a kick_until date on the object and check that in deserialization, then until its after that date, return an unauth session in deserialization.

Option 2: Middleware applied to all routes that checks this information and a call to `req.session.destroy();` to force the session destroyed. (Doesn't prevent a log back in, but the session wont stick and will redestroy if you forget to toggle the field that determined that should be kicked after doing it the first time)