# get ids of all logged in users in express.js

Tags: javascript, json, express

I'm currently working on project and am trying to grab a list of currently logged in user ids. I've read this question [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104698/trying-to-view-all-logged-in-users-in-express-js-node-js-passport-js) however I'm having trouble accessing properties of the object.

Currently I have the following:

```
let sessions = req.sessionStore.sessions
console.log(JSON.stringify(sessions))
```

This gives me the following output in the console:

```
{"zQPGZTGLKSLna0qsB25UH2B-LHq-bhGj":"{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"onlineUsers\":[],\"passport\":{\"user\":{\"id\":\"102960089981993612086\",\"displayName\":\"John Doe\",\"name\":{\"familyName\":\"Kent\",\"givenName\":\"John\"},\"emails\":[{\"value\":\"user1@gmail.com\",\"type\":\"account\"}],\"photos\":[{\"value\":\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-gSSOtDlqObQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABo/Glisghf57868BXEc/photo.jpg?sz=50\"}],\"provider\":\"google\",\"_raw\":\"{\\n \\\"kind\\\": \\\"plus#person\\\",\\n \\\"etag\\\": \\\"\\\\\\\"EhMivDE25UysA1ltNG8tqFM2v-A/QhO28UAZgzAMK8E3xGjKjeSkOdw\\\\\\\"\\\",\\n \\\"emails\\\": [\\n  {\\n   \\\"value\\\": \\\"user1@gmail.com\\\",\\n   \\\"type\\\": \\\"account\\\"\\n  }\\n ],\\n \\\"objectType\\\": \\\"person\\\",\\n \\\"id\\\": \\\"102960089981993612086\\\",\\n \\\"displayName\\\": \\\"John Doe\\\",\\n \\\"name\\\": {\\n  \\\"familyName\\\": \\\"Doe\\\",\\n  \\\"givenName\\\": \\\"John\\\"\\n },\\n \\\"image\\\": {\\n  \\\"url\\\": \\\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-gSSOtDfhjgObQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABo/Glfh5767BXEc/photo.jpg?sz=50\\\",\\n  \\\"isDefault\\\": false\\n },\\n \\\"isPlusUser\\\": false,\\n \\\"language\\\": \\\"en_GB\\\",\\n \\\"verified\\\": false,\\n \\\"domain\\\": \\\"gmail.com\\\"\\n}\\n\",\"_json\":{\"kind\":\"plus#person\",\"etag\":\"\\\"EhMivDE25UysA1ltNG8tqFM2v-A/QhO28UAZgzAMK8E3xGjKjeSkOdw\\\"\",\"emails\":[{\"value\":\"user1@gmail.com\",\"type\":\"account\"}],\"objectType\":\"person\",\"id\":\"102960089981993612086\",\"displayName\":\"John Doe\",\"name\":{\"familyName\":\"Doe\",\"givenName\":\"John\"},\"image\":{\"url\":\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-gSSO547gjfgQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABo/GlispvZBXEc/photo.jpg?sz=50\",\"isDefault\":false},\"isPlusUser\":false,\"language\":\"en_GB\",\"verified\":false,\"domain\":\"gmail.com\"},\"userId\":1,\"userEmail\":\"user1@gmail.com\",\"onlineUsers\":[1]}}}","5wgujtyTy4VKE5nuSdFFn5KeKjw_pN7S":"{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"onlineUsers\":[],\"passport\":{\"user\":{\"id\":\"103606132706227313142\",\"displayName\":\"jane doe\",\"name\":{\"familyName\":\"doe\",\"givenName\":\"jane\"},\"emails\":[{\"value\":\"user2@gmail.com\",\"type\":\"account\"}],\"photos\":[{\"value\":\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2Xu2xfgJLj4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAE8/KNkdMSydfe8/photo.jpg?sz=50\"}],\"gender\":\"male\",\"provider\":\"google\",\"_raw\":\"{\\n \\\"kind\\\": \\\"plus#person\\\",\\n \\\"etag\\\": \\\"\\\\\\\"EhMivDE25UysA1ltNG8tqFM2v-A/WzeABRHoHgmU-_X-r9oFDYUKNnY\\\\\\\"\\\",\\n \\\"gender\\\": \\\"male\\\",\\n \\\"emails\\\": [\\n  {\\n   \\\"value\\\": \\\"user2@gmail.com\\\",\\n   \\\"type\\\": \\\"account\\\"\\n  }\\n ],\\n \\\"urls\\\": [\\n  {\\n   \\\"value\\\": \\\"http://www.youtube.com/user/user28469746\\\",\\n
  \\\"type\\\": \\\"otherProfile\\\",\\n   \\\"label\\\": \\\"Programming Tutorials\\\"\\n  }\\n ],\\n \\\"objectType\\\": \\\"person\\\",\\n \\\"id\\\": \\\"103606132706227313142\\\",\\n \\\"displayName\\\": \\\"jane doe\\\",\\n \\\"name\\\": {\\n  \\\"familyName\\\": \\\"doe\\\",\\n  \\\"givenName\\\": \\\"jane\\\"\\n },\\n \\\"url\\\": \\\"https://plus.google.com/10360613547706227313142\\\",\\n \\\"image\\\": {\\n  \\\"url\\\": \\\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2Xu2fhgJLj4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAE8/KNkdMSyEYe8/photo.jpg?sz=50\\\",\\n  \\\"isDefault\\\": false\\n },\\n \\\"isPlusUser\\\": true,\\n \\\"language\\\": \\\"en\\\",\\n \\\"circledByCount\\\": 1,\\n \\\"verified\\\": false\\n}\\n\",\"_json\":{\"kind\":\"plus#person\",\"etag\":\"\\\"EhMivDE25UysA1ltNG8tqFM2v-A/WzeABRHoHgmU-_X-r9oFDYUKNnY\\\"\",\"gender\":\"male\",\"emails\":[{\"value\":\"user2@gmail.com\",\"type\":\"account\"}],\"urls\":[{\"value\":\"http://www.youtube.com/user/user4577576\",\"type\":\"otherProfile\",\"label\":\"Programming Tutorials\"}],\"objectType\":\"person\",\"id\":\"1036061327056676727313142\",\"displayName\":\"jane doe\",\"name\":{\"familyName\":\"doe\",\"givenName\":\"matt\"},\"url\":\"https://plus.google.com/103606132706227313142\",\"image\":{\"url\":\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2Xu2x56564Lj4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAE8/KNkdM544EYe8/photo.jpg?sz=50\",\"isDefault\":false},\"isPlusUser\":true,\"language\":\"en\",\"circledByCount\":1,\"verified\":false}}}}"}
```

As you can see there are two logged in users. I'd like to iterate over the object and output both the user ids within `passport` to the console.

I've tried the following:

```
for (sesh in sessions) {
    console.log(sessions[sesh].passport.user.id)
}
```

but this gives me undefined.

I've also attempted using `sessions.forEach()` however this also doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to parse the JSON first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored as a JSON, you need to parse it in order to be able to retrieve properties:

```
for (sesh in sessions) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(sessions[sesh]).passport.user.id)
}
```